# Not able to generate sonarqube report locally as I am getting the EXECUTION FAILURE with error log :Tasks support was removed in SonarQube 7.6

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarlint, sonarscanner

My requirement is to get the code coverage in local using Visual studio :

SonarQube server is up . I have attached the snapshot as shown :

`jvm 1    | 2022.02.14 16:04:07 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ce] is up jvm 1    | 2022.02.14 16:04:07 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is up`

Sonar-Scanner is done but when I am executing the sonar-start , I am getting following error while running sonarscanner :
There is no specific error which is causing execution failure .

```
C:\IM\Abb.Ability.Edge.OfflineInfoModel_NEW>sonar-scanner D"sonar.projectKey=test" -D"sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000" -D"sonar.login=73b65b07a08bb61e7b57af8c1f3ca80eeb52811f" -D"sonar.projectName=test" --debug
16:19:46.195 INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\sonar-scanner-cli-4.0.0.1744-windows\sonar-scanner-4.0.0.1744-windows\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
16:19:46.200 INFO: Project root configuration file: C:\IM\Abb.Ability.Edge.OfflineInfoModel_NEW\sonar-project.properties
16:19:46.236 INFO: SonarQube Scanner 4.0.0.1744
16:19:46.237 INFO: Java 11.0.3 AdoptOpenJDK (64-bit)
16:19:46.239 INFO: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
16:19:46.382 DEBUG: keyStore is :
16:19:46.383 DEBUG: keyStore type is : pkcs12
16:19:46.383 DEBUG: keyStore provider is :
16:19:46.384 DEBUG: init keystore
16:19:46.386 DEBUG: init keymanager of type SunX509
16:19:47.098 DEBUG: Create: C:\Users\INAYGUP1\.sonar\cache
16:19:47.100 INFO: User cache: C:\Users\INAYGUP1\.sonar\cache
16:19:47.100 DEBUG: Create: C:\Users\INAYGUP1\.sonar\cache\_tmp
16:19:47.104 DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
16:19:47.111 DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
16:19:47.112 DEBUG: Download: http://localhost:9000/batch/index
16:19:47.172 DEBUG: Get bootstrap completed
16:19:47.177 DEBUG: Create isolated classloader...
16:19:47.187 DEBUG: Start temp cleaning...
16:19:47.198 DEBUG: Temp cleaning done
16:19:47.199 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
16:19:47.214 INFO: SonarQube server 8.9.7
16:19:47.217 DEBUG: Execution execute
16:19:48.082 DEBUG: Community 8.9.7.52159
16:19:48.260 INFO: Load global settings
16:19:48.317 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/settings/values.protobuf | time=54ms
16:19:48.360 INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=100ms
16:19:48.363 INFO: Server id: BF41A1F2-AX73y1fBlJv9Eogawl22
16:19:48.369 INFO: User cache: C:\Users\INAYGUP1\.sonar\cache
16:19:48.374 INFO: Load/download plugins
16:19:48.374 INFO: Load plugins index
16:19:48.386 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/plugins/installed | time=11ms
16:19:48.428 INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=54ms
16:19:48.509 INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=134ms
16:19:48.564 DEBUG: Plugins:
16:19:48.564 DEBUG:   * Python Code Quality and Security 3.4.1.8066 (python)
16:19:48.566 DEBUG:   * CSS Code Quality and Security 1.4.2.2002 (cssfamily)
16:19:48.571 DEBUG:   * Go Code Quality and Security 1.8.3.2219 (go)
16:19:48.574 DEBUG:   * JaCoCo 1.1.1.1157 (jacoco)
16:19:48.575 DEBUG:   * Kotlin Code Quality and Security 1.8.3.2219 (kotlin)
16:19:48.576 DEBUG:   * JavaScript/TypeScript Code Quality and Security 7.4.4.15624 (javascript)
16:19:48.576 DEBUG:   * Ruby Code Quality and Security 1.8.3.2219 (ruby)
16:19:48.577 DEBUG:   * Scala Code Quality and Security 1.8.3.2219 (sonarscala)
16:19:48.578 DEBUG:   * C# Code Quality and Security 8.22.0.31243 (csharp)
16:19:48.578 DEBUG:   * Java Code Quality and Security 6.15.1.26025 (java)
16:19:48.579 DEBUG:   * HTML Code Quality and Security 3.4.0.2754 (web)
16:19:48.580 DEBUG:   * Flex Code Quality and Security 2.6.1.2564 (flex)
16:19:48.580 DEBUG:   * XML Code Quality and Security 2.2.0.2973 (xml)
16:19:48.581 DEBUG:   * PHP Code Quality and Security 3.17.0.7439 (php)
16:19:48.582 DEBUG:   * VB.NET Code Quality and Security 8.22.0.31243 (vbnet)
16:19:48.619 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:19:48.619 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
16:19:48.620 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:19:48.621 INFO: Total time: 2.456s
16:19:48.649 INFO: Final Memory: 4M/54M
16:19:48.650 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:19:48.659 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
Tasks support was removed in SonarQube 7.6.'
```

Also , I would like to know how to provide the configuration like Debug ,  Release or any custom configuration while generating the sonar report .